# Display only pending products based on user role in WooCommerce admin product list

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, backend, user-roles

I would like to display only pending products in WooCommerce admin product list for shop manager and hide all trash

Using CSS I was able to partially hide items that I don't want to be visible:

```css
.current,
.draft,
.publish,
.search-box,
.byorder,
.tablenav.top,
    .page-title-action {
display: none;
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

---

This is not sufficient so I also use:

```php
function exclude_other_author_products($query) {
  $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
  if (in_array('administrator', $current_user->shop_manager)
    return $query;
if ($query->query['post_type'] == 'product' && $query->is_main_query()) {
    $query->set('author__in', $current_user->ID);
}
 }

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'exclude_other_author_products');
```

However, this produces a critical error: `syntax error, unexpected token "return"`

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `post_status`

- `publish` - a published post or page
- `pending` - post is pending review
- `draft` - a post in draft status
- `auto-draft` - a newly created post, with no content
- `future` - a post to publish in the future
- `private` - not visible to users who are not logged in
- `inherit` - a revision. see get_children.
- `trash` - post is in trashbin.

---

**Note:** Both the user roles and the post statuses consist of an array. So several can be added, separated by a comma

so you get:

```php
function action_pre_get_posts( $query ) {   
    global $pagenow, $post_type;
    
    // Targeting admin product list
    if ( $query->is_admin && $pagenow === 'edit.php' && $post_type === 'product' ) {
        // Get current user
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
    
        // Roles
        $roles = (array) $user->roles;
        
        // Roles to check
        $roles_to_check = array( 'shop_manager' );
        
        // Compare
        $compare = array_diff( $roles, $roles_to_check );
    
        // Result is empty
        if ( empty ( $compare ) ) {
            // Set "post status"
            $query->set( 'post_status', array( 'pending' ) );
            
            /* OPTIONAL
            // Set "posts per page"
            $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 20 );

            // Set "paged"
            $query->set( 'paged', ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1 ) );
            */
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'action_pre_get_posts', 10, 1 );
```